# What's the navigation mode of OnNavigatedTo method when Windows Phone application restore from tombstoning？

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When Windows Phone application restore from tombstoning, in page's OnNavigatedTo Method, I am wondering whether it's NavigationMode is Back or New ?

Comment: It is easy enough to confirm by running the Debugger with the Debug settings of your project set to "always tombstone". Can't remember off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After tombstoning NavigationMode will be set to Back.

You can as Paul Annetts said in the comment verify and debug this by going to Project-> ProjectName Properties -> Debug -> "Tombstone upon deactivation while debugging".

Answer (score 1):

NavigationMode is 'Back'. To understand it more refer :

http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/13/tombstoning-made-easy-in-windows-phone-mvvm/

also one possible clean solution can be found here :

http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/03/13/tombstoning-made-easy-in-windows-phone-mvvm/